# Book recommendation on differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation

Before asking this question, I have [read this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-references-and-book-recommendations) and I believe I have a few specific requirements that will reduce the chances of this question to be opinion based.

I am looking for a book on differential equations. To set some goal, let's say I want to be able to understand what Black–Scholes model is about and how it works(from the mathematical standpoint).

As for my current education, I have a PhD degree in applied mathematics and spent several years working in Machine Learning domain in industry(the industry I'm working in is not related to finance). I have never had a course on differential equations though.

Taking into account my current background, any suggestions to get me started ?

Thanks

Comment: PhD and you have never taken a differential equation course. How is that possible?

Comment: @Milan My Master Degree was in Control Theory, our university just did not have this subject in their program.

Comment: Black-Scholes is a partial differential equation.  So you probably need two books, the first on ordinary differential equations, the second on partial differential equations.  But even before that, there is the question of how much of your calculus you remember.

Comment: @drsealks: Maybe look at the references in a book like Black-Scholes and Beyond: Option Pricing Models 1st Edition, by Neil A. Chriss  (Author), and Basic Black-Scholes: Option Pricing and Trading (Revised Fourth) by Timothy Falcon Crack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good book that I used during my first semester of graduate school is [An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation: Mathematics, Stochastics and Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521547571) by Desmond Higham. Professor Higham maintains a [website](http://personal.strath.ac.uk/d.j.higham/option_book.html) for the book which includes Matlab code and hints to the odd number exercises. No knowledge of measure theory is necessary and almost all of the derivations are done through techniques learned in calculus and differential equations. The Black-Scholes PDE is covered in the second half of the book.

Another good supplementary book is [Financial Calculus: An Introduction to Derivative Pricing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AKE1RHQ) by Martin Baxter. This book goes through Ito’s Lemma before the derivation of the Black-Scholes PDE.